java -- using wildcard imports, qualifying some names
Suppose we have packages A and B which both have C, and lots of other things, mostly non-overlapping. Is this acceptable:
import A.*;
import B.*;

// qualify usages of C as B.C or A.C

If so, is there some official source or documentation regarding this?

Does this answer your question? Why is using a wild card with a Java import statement bad?

no @Progman , this is a different question, and deserves its own.

I'm not sure if the question intends the word 'acceptable' as: "Is this legal java / possible" in which case, [A] yes, [B] why ask? It takes less time to write it up and run it. Or, if the word 'acceptable' refers to 'proper style'. I have therefore voted to close this question as inappropriate: Asking for opinion. Because the other option is not kind to the asker.

@rzwitserloot the question is legality/where it says it's allowed in the docs, which is valid. Just because something runs and compiles doesn't mean it's necessarily valid code, at least in the world of C++/C.


Name Ambiguities:
If a member in one package shares its name with a member in another package and both packages are imported, you must refer to each member by its qualified name.

Source
So, long story short, if you have a class C in package A, and another class C in package B, you can't import both in the way you described and expect it to work without explicitly using A.C and B.C to refer to those classes.
